# If useState is not supported by React server components how do we assign component state for rendering

Tags: reactjs, server, react-server-components

Im trying to understand React server components and how to render component state without the use of useState and useEffect. I have created a server component with an embedded client component and both fetch a small amount of data and display as JSON.

The client component works as expected and renders the json data fetched from the API.

main.client.tsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

export default function Main() {
    let [data, setData] = useState(undefined);

    async function fetchData() {
        let value = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
        let result = await value.json();
        let slice = result.slice(0,2);
        return slice;
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchData().then(value => {
            setData(value);
            console.log("data", data)
        });
    }, [])

    return (<div className="component">
        <h1>Client Main</h1>
        {data &&
            <div>
                <pre>
                    {JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}
                </pre>
            </div>
        }
    </div>)
}
```

The server component doesnt re-render the json data. Its basiically a duplicate of the client code without useEffect, useRef and useState because they are not availabe on the server.

It renders the initialised data but not the fetched data.

main.server.tsx

```
import Client from "../components/main.client"

export default function Main() {
    let data = {key: "initial value"};
    let hello = "hello world";
    
    async function fetchData() {
        let value = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
        let result = await value.json();
        let slice = result.slice(0,2);
        return slice;
    }

    fetchData().then(value => {
        data = [...value];
        console.log("data", data)
    });

    return (<div className="component">
        <h1>Server Main</h1>
        {hello}
        {data &&
            <div>
                <pre>
                    {JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}
                </pre>
            </div>
        }
        <Client/>
    </div>)
}
```

how can i correctly assign the data array (returned from the fetch) so it renders on the server?

Comment: You can use async/await directly in your server components if you want to fetch on the server. State and effects generally aren't necessary unless you have a component running on the client that needs to do something interactive.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Next.JS, it's probably that you need to use "'use client';" before any import to fix this problem. See this example:

```
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import { Inter } from "@next/font/google";
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: "use client"; if we mention this then ssg not working?